# Share cookies between flutter webviews

Tags: javascript, android, ios, flutter, webview

I'm developing a flutter app with Webviews using this plugin: [Flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview).

At first, I am loading a webview with the login page in a own domain and later redirect users to a different domain url. On this second url I inject an iframe menu loaded from the same site where the user was logged before. I need the login cookies accesible on this iframe, but i can't get it working.

Menu is loaded and the cookies exists, but the menu injected with an iframe in the second domain doesnt' works.

By the way, i need a way to communicate between javascript loaded in the url and a flutter webview. I tried with the services included in the plugin, but doesn't work.

Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cookies_jar package available for flutter to achieve the behaviour you are expecting.